# Multithreaded JavaMail: is it possible?

Tags: concurrency, gmail, imap, jakarta-mail

[JavaMail can only read one message at a time through IMAP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5876358/bulk-fetch-mail-bodies-using-javamail-api-and-imap). Threrefore, I am wondering whether opening several connections and reading emails concurrently is a good wordaround. Has anyone done this? I am concerned about the server (Gmail) refusing to open multiple connections or throttling them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have tried this. it seems to work fine, because it seems completely fine (and common) to have 2 different clients connected to gmail on different computers. However, i sometimes get random errors from gmail, and in that case its one additional factor to debug.